# Converting to Judaism and circumcision

Tags: halacha, conversion-to-judaism, medicine, brit-milah

I am converting to Judaism after living Jewishly for half my life. I am 27 and there was simply no way to convert for years (and I was a minor when I first sought conversion). Now I have had a Beit Din and am soon to have hatafat dam brit. But I was concerned that I did not look circumcised. My mother had me circumcised as a baby in a hospital but I do not look circumcised, so I went to a urologist and he said what probably happened was I did not have as much skin removed as many who are circumcised have removed and so I don't appear circumcised. So I was wondering if I still qualify for hatafat dam brit? I told my rabbi and he and I are searching for other cases where a person was circumcised as a baby (not by a mohel) and then doesn't appear to be circumcised and whether or not they still qualify for the simple hatafat dam brit. I was nervous about revealing this, but I am intellectually curious as to how one should proceed. Thanks.

Comment: You should really ask your rav about this. I am no Mohel, but the appearance of the circumcision can be very fundamental to whether or not you need to be circumcised again. Circumcision, as defined by the medical profession, may not mean the same as it does in the Rabbinic Hebrew.

Comment: You're going to want to see Shulchan Arukh YD 264:1,3, and 6. Essentially, if at the original circumcision they uncovered (proximally) the majority of the glans at ever point around its circumference as well as the majority of the circumference of the corona, then you _might_ be able to get away with just a HDB. However, if the skin has spread back beyond those lines you still might need a proper Milah (as the original Milah done by a non-Jew may not be (fully) kosher per ShA ibid. :1, cf. Shkah ibid. 12) and if...

Comment: ...the skin has spread so much by now that even during an erection it doesn't look circumcised then you would almost certainly need more cutting even with a HDB. Basically you're going to have to show this to a Mohel.

Comment: ציצין מעכבים? או אין ציצין מעכבים

Comment: I don't mind a brit. I really don't. I just want to know what's required. I'll consult a mohel later this week. I live in a non-Jewish area and want to complete my conversion. My location kind of drags things out a bit.

Comment: dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/50941/759