# Self inspection of a bris milah

Tags: halacha, brit-milah

Is it possible for an adult to inspect his own milah to determine if the milah was done in a halachically proper manner? Are there any picture guides or some other type of resources that would help someone who is completely ignorant in the details of what a bris milah entails, to educate himself to the actual practical details of the laws and in turn allow him to inspect his own milah?

Comment: Why would you think this isn't possible? Are you worried about Paskining for yourself (like Roeh Bekhorot Atzmo)?

Comment: Mark for the record and for all future readers there is no such thing as a circumcision inspection. Whoever claims to be doing this type of inspection should be reported to the police. Even if he is the Rosh yeshiva or the Rosh yeshivas son.

Comment: @user6591 i personally know a dr./mohel who in the mikvah found someone about whom it was paskened that he needs a bris with a brocho. what is wrong with this inspection?

Comment: @hazoriz this is usually a ruse for molesters. There was a pretty famous molester who used this exact ploy on many unsuspecting people. If anyone has a doubt about their circumcision they can contact a competent mohel. Your story sounds strange to say the least.

Comment: @user6591 it is not better to educate people an ervah halochos, (and bris halochos). Then to (make a new issur and) ban people from checking people's brisim (it seems in resent history people would wash naked in rivers, or public baths , and non Jews would make fun of Jews that they were cercomzised , and in the hanuka story we also learn about Jews being embarrassed (from the non Jews so it seems it was completely normal for them to look), (there is no isur to seeing other people's gid, unless you are davening)) (btw the inspection requires no tuching)

Comment: @user6591 if you only ban this way the mnotfim (molesters) will find other way to seduce their victoms

Comment: @hazoriz There is almost no situation where a visual inspection will show anything. Unless there are tzitzin hamiakvin which is so unlikely we can discard that, there is never anything to inspect. I didn't make a ban I am educating the public. As for public bathing, there were rules instituted for decency such as covering one's erva on the way up back from the river. Not all molesting involves touching. Putting someone in a sexually compromised situation, even if only for viewing, is wrong and punishable by law.

Comment: @hazoriz Also, if the way you personally know about this dr/rabbi having done this is because he told you so and he' inspected' you, call the authorities.

Comment: @user6591 this might be American law not jew law, there is nothing to inspect exsept tztitzin hamiakvin , I was not yet in the mikva with him (btw I know my bris is good) he was bosting how he helped a Jew (he gave him the bris himself) , he also does dead people (when the hevra kadisha calles him) covering the ervah is one thing but forbidding to look is a different story

Answer (score 3):

When inspection is helpful,  self inspection is good enough.   For negayim,  a man cannot check his own negayim,  but for most isurim a man can check himself for shechita,  Kashrut and all isurim.

There are a lot of question around a circumcision as other users have said.

We will try to answer a few of them.

1. If residues of foreskin remain, have we to cut them? The Shulchan Aruch says in Yore Dea siman 264, se'if 5, that if in some place a residue of foreskin covers the majority of the length of the glans, even in a small area, he still needs to circumcise as if he was not circumcised. The Baer Heytev (in name of an opinion reported in Bet Yosef and Shach) adds that if the majority of the circumference of the corona glandis is covered, he is not regarded as circumcised. This part of the inspection may be a self inspection.
2. Is it important to know who  was the Mohel? The Shulchan Aruch in 264, 1, said that even a child or a woman can circumcise,  bediavad even a NJ makes a valuable circumcision. But Rama requires brit bloodshed.
3. The time of the Brit. Rama at the same place explains that a child who was circumcised before his 8th day of life needs also brit bloodshed.

For 2 and 3, I am not convinced that a Jew needs to investigate to ensure that the conditions was fulfilled.